# Android Emulator with multiple environments

Tags: android-emulator

I am looking for a Android Emulator which would support multiple environments. Free and open source one is an advantage of course.

I am looking something similar to MEmu on windows (I just transferred from windows).

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Are you open to using a Virtual Machine, with a different Guest VM for each environment?

Comment: What about andriod studio (https://developer.android.com/studio).I don't know if this supports multiple environments.

Comment: I tried installing MEmu on VM, but that did not work because there are not appropriate drivers installed on VM

Comment: still waiting for recommendations